# How to natural-sort a collection of objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, sql-order-by, lodash, natural-sort

Belong is an example of my collection of objects.

```
const a = [
    {name: "John", size: "100"},
    {name: "John", size: "80"},
    {name: "John", size: "82"},
    {name: "John", size: "110"},
    {name: "John", size: "70"},
    {name: "John", size: "M"},
    {name: "John", size: "S"},
    {name: "John", size: "XS"},
    {name: "John", size: "L"},
    {name: "John", size: "XL"},
]
```

How can I sort it in a natural way in JavaScript that 100 is greater than 80 and that 100 comes after 80 as an example?

The challange is that size's value is a mix of numbers and strings.

The desired result on ascending order:

```
[
    {name: "John", size: "70"},
    {name: "John", size: "80"},
    {name: "John", size: "82"},
    {name: "John", size: "100"},
    {name: "John", size: "110"},
    {name: "John", size: "L"},
    {name: "John", size: "M"},
    {name: "John", size: "S"},
    {name: "John", size: "XL"},
    {name: "John", size: "XS"},
]
```

The desired result on descending order:

```
[
    {name: "John", size: "XS"},
    {name: "John", size: "XL"},
    {name: "John", size: "S"},
    {name: "John", size: "M"},
    {name: "John", size: "L"},
    {name: "John", size: "110"},
    {name: "John", size: "100"},
    {name: "John", size: "82"},
    {name: "John", size: "80"},
    {name: "John", size: "70"},
]
```

I have tried Lodash JavaScript Library this way on ascending order but it does not sort it right because it sees `100` less than `80` because `100` starts with `1`.

```
_.orderBy(a, ["size"], ["asc"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ascending and Descending order

```js
const arr = [{name: "John", size: "100"},{name: "John", size: "80"},{name: "John", size: "82"},{name: "John", size: "110"},{name: "John", size: "70"},{name: "John", size: "M"},{name: "John", size: "S"},{name: "John", size: "XS"},{name: "John", size: "L"},{name: "John", size: "XL"}],
      handler = (a, b, desc) => {
        if (isNaN(+a) && isNaN(+b)) return (desc ? b.localeCompare(a) : a.localeCompare(b));
        else if (!isNaN(+a) && !isNaN(+b)) return (desc ? (+b - +a) : (+a - +b));
        else if (isNaN(+a)) return (desc ? -1 : 1); 
        else return (desc ? 1 : -1);
      },
      descending = arr.sort(({size: a}, {size: b}) => handler(a, b, true)),
      ascending = [...arr].sort(({size: a}, {size: b}) => handler(a, b));

console.log("Ascending")
console.log(ascending);
console.log("Descending")
console.log(descending);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your solution works correctly for my case of thousands of records on one page. How could I sort on multiple properies e.g. name and size?

Answer (score 3):

As you are using loadsh already. Simply write a function that evaluates if size is String or Integer and then it will sort asc for you.

for desc, you can just reverse the asc array.

```js
const a = [ {name: "John", size: "100"}, {name: "John", size: "80"}, {name: "John", size: "82"}, {name: "John", size: "110"}, {name: "John", size: "70"}, {name: "John", size: "M"},    {name: "John", size: "S"}, {name: "John", size: "XS"}, {name: "John", size: "L"}, {name: "John", size: "XL"} ];

// ascednding
const b = _.orderBy(a, function(e) { return isNaN(e.size) ? e.size: parseInt(e.size)}, ["asc"]);
console.log("ASCENDING::");
console.log(b);

//descending
const c = _.reverse(b);
console.log("DESCENDING::");
console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution works good. But in my case, I have thousands of records on my page and I use Vue.js and its reactivity feature to update the table. Then it does not sort correctly. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [
  {name: "John", size: "100"},
  {name: "John", size: "80"},
  {name: "John", size: "82"},
  {name: "John", size: "110"},
  {name: "John", size: "70"},
  {name: "John", size: "M"},
  {name: "John", size: "S"},
  {name: "John", size: "XS"},
  {name: "John", size: "L"},
  {name: "John", size: "XL"},
 ]
// ascending
const sorted = arr => [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.size.localeCompare(b.size, 'en', {numeric: true}))
console.log(sorted(a))
```

Comment: This is the superior answer in 2022.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let array_data = [
    {name: "John", size: "70"},
    {name: "John", size: "80"},
    {name: "John", size: "82"},
    {name: "John", size: "100"},
    {name: "John", size: "110"},
    {name: "John", size: "L"},
    {name: "John", size: "M"},
    {name: "John", size: "S"},
    {name: "John", size: "XL"},
    {name: "John", size: "XS"},
];

    let  sorted = array_data.sort((a, b) => {return parseInt(a.size) - parseInt(b.size);});
    console.log(sorted);
```

Normal sort javascript function will be work.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with normal JavaScript logic. You can explicitly create a sizes mapping that will help you to sort the values according to the requirement:

```js
const a = [
    {name: "John", size: "100"},
    {name: "John", size: "80"},
    {name: "John", size: "82"},
    {name: "John", size: "110"},
    {name: "John", size: "70"},
    {name: "John", size: "M"},
    {name: "John", size: "S"},
    {name: "John", size: "XS"},
    {name: "John", size: "L"},
    {name: "John", size: "XL"},
];
var sizes = {
  '100': 3,
  '80': 1,
  '82': 2,
  '110': 4,
  '70': 0,
  'M': 6,
  'S': 7,
  'XS': 9,
  'L': 5,
  'XL': 8,
}
//ascending
a.sort((x, y) => {
  return sizes[x.size] - sizes[y.size];
});

console.log(a);

//descending
a.sort((x, y) => {
  return sizes[y.size] - sizes[x.size];
});

console.log(a);
```